# connectivity issue to nougat ocr using python

Tags: python, ssl, ocr

I am currently trying to perform OCR on PDF which contains an image in it. I came across the youtube tutorial to use Nougat OCR from facebook research. Since my deployment server will not have internet, I may get SSL issue when trying to access the configuration. Can you please advice me how to handle that ? Below is the error reproduced.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443):  url: /facebookresearch/nougat/releases/download/0.1.0-small/config.json
```

Is there anyway I can use this json in local ? If yes, where should be destination folder? If there is any other method which can perform state of the art, please suggest as well.

Comment: You would probably need to look at the source for Nougat and where it stores those files locally, and move them along to your deployment server.